# How to fork from a running process?

Tags: bash

I often do this:

```
$ gitk &
```

To start a program (like `gitk` in this case, but it doesn`t matter which) and get back to the shell prompt to continue working in the same shell. How would you go about it, after you already wrote

```
$ gitk
```

without the `&`? Is there a key combination like `^z`, that puts the process in the background but without interrupting it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have started the process without `&`, it'll run in the foreground. Press `Ctrl+Z` which will stop the process, then enter the command `bg` to resume the process execution in background.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call an external program, like `ls`, or `gitk`, or whatever, you execute a `fork`.  Running a program with `&` in Bash does a lot more than a fork.  It creates a new process group which runs in the background.

Ctrl+z usually has the effect (using a signal) of placing the job in a stopped state in the background, restart with `bg`.  I say "usually" because it can be changed, using `stty`.  To list your terminal settings (and to see other magic Ctrl keys), try `stty -a`.

A characteristic of background jobs is that they don't normally have access to the keyboard, but do have access to the screen.  That could be mixed with other output, so you can use `stty tostop` to  prevent it.  The job has to be brought into foreground to use the screen, or use `stty -tostop`.  Jobs are brought into the foreground using `fg`.

Note that you can have many background jobs, see them by typing `jobs`.  Some commands, including `fg`, `bg`, and `kill`, take an optional job number (prefixed `%`).

Comment: Feels a little bit unstructured, but a lot of valuable info, thx!

Comment: @erikb85: unstructured?  Which part?  I see it as very structured, but maybe that's because it has remained unchanged for over 25 years.

Comment: I mean your text looks a little unstructured, because it contains a lot of information. More like a quote from a face-to-face conversation, then a descriptive answer on a website. But after reading it twice I got it and can use it now.